# php multi session array update

Tags: php, arrays, session

I want to update the product inventory would be glad if you help I could not.
My product list array

```
$_SESSION['item'];
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [product_id] => 9 [stock] => 20 ) 
[1] => Array ( [product_id] => 8 [stock] => 30 ) 
[2] => Array ( [product_id] => 7 [stock] => 26 ) 
[3] => Array ( [product_id] => 6 [stock] => 42 ) 
)
```

I do

```
$product_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_id']);
$stock  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['stock']);
$found = false;
foreach($_SESSION['item'] as $product){
    if($product_id == $product['product_id']) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if($found){
    $_SESSION['item'][$product_id]['stock'] += $stock;
}else{

    // go get new product and add to $_SESSION['item']
}
```

Comment: Well and what's the question? Where is an error? What's does not work?

Comment: What's the value of `$found` after the foreach loop?

Comment: not update product stock

Comment: its not going to work, `stock` is not a key of `product_id` i would restructure the array using the product_id as the first level key

Comment: `$_SESSION['item']` is **NOT indexed by product_id**!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$product_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_id']);
$stock  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['stock']);
$found = false;
foreach($_SESSION['item'] as $index => $product){
    if($product_id == $product['product_id']) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if($found){
    $_SESSION['item'][$index]['stock'] += $stock;
}else{
    // go get new product and add to $_SESSION['item']
}
```

Explain: the `$_SESSION['item']` array is **not indexed by the `product_id`**. So you have to get and store an index of the current array item in the foreach loop and use it to update of the `$_SESSION['item']` array.

Comment: Great, I'm pleased :) As reward you can vote for my answer and mark it as answer. Thank you.

Comment: How points are given :) I'm tossing up arrow says 15 people need more